# Intercepting property setting in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, orm

I'm new to Fluent NHibernate, and have what I think should be a simple question.  The problem is that I can't seem to find a simple answer anywhere.

I have a database column that is an `nvarchar` (SQL Server).  It should map to a model property that is a `System.Uri`.  The problem is that `string` doesn't implicitly convert to `Uri`.  Is there a way to "intercept" the setting of the property to use custom logic?

```
Map(x => x.WebAddress); // WebAddress in the DB is nvarchar, and it's a System.Uri in the model

// would like to find something like what I have below
Map(x => x.WebAddress).Intercept<string, Uri>(y => new Uri(y));
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `IUserType`, this is an NHibernate feature rather than Fluent NHibernate. You'd then use `CustomType<YourUserType>()` on your property.

A google search reveals many different examples of implementing the `IUserType` interface, such as http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/usertype.html.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could take credit, but I believe this example will do exactly what you are hoping to do. http://swik.net/tag4sree/Hibernate+-+Objects/Implementing+custom+types+in+nHibernate/b3s2p